# Strange difference between EditText added in layout XML and from code

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, view

There is difference between text edit added in activity_main.xml and one added from code.

That is how they look.

[image: text fields]

Code of EditText added from xml.

[image: xml code]

And code of EditText added programmatically.

[image: code]

Function getDisplayInfo just get width and height of the screen. It does nothing connected with ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's because the background color isn't set on the new `EditText` since the background color is set in xml then you add a `View` to it. You need to then set the background color to your newly added `EditText`.

I believe something like

```
editT.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0F0"));
```

should work.

Comment: But it has no underline while not focused.

Answer (score 0):

`EditText` added from xml has preformed look and feel but if we are adding it from java code it may require to set additional attributes to set look and feel

```
EditText etName = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
etName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.BlueBackground);
```

Comment: I've tried to add some parameters with LayoutParams, but there is noting about style or how it must look.

Comment: EditText is inherited from TextView so you can use TextView method setBackgroundResource(int) to set background as look in xml